# How to load custom.css after styles-l.css

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, theme, css, luma-theme

I am working on custom theme and the parent theme is **blank**.I have added the below code in default_head_block.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
    <css src="css/styles-m.css" />
    <css src="css/styles-l.css" media="screen and (min-width: 768px)"/>
    <css src="css/print.css" media="print" />
</head>
```

But in view source of browser **custom.css** loads before **styles-l.css** how can i fix it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think you need to fix this. Look how Magento 2 render head information..

```
class \Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config\Renderer {
...
public function renderHeadContent()
{
    ...
    $result .= $this->renderAssets($this->getAvailableResultGroups());
    $result .= $this->pageConfig->getIncludes();
    return $result;
}
```

> $result .= $this->pageConfig->getIncludes();

you can add you custom scripts in admin. Navigate to Content > Design > Configuration > Select Theme > HTML Head section > Scripts and Style Sheets field

But I think the best way would be use less processor via grunt to create your own styles.
You can find more information here http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html
and http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css_debug.html

Answer (score 1):

You can define using the order attribute, below is the code snippet:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
    <css src="css/styles-m.css" />
    <css src="css/styles-l.css" media="screen and (min-width: 768px)"/>
    <css src="css/print.css" media="print" />
    <css src="css/custom.css" order="0"/>
</head>
```

Comment: order="0" is not an accepted argument (i mean as of version 2.2.x)

Comment: Its working for me i tried in latest version 2.2.X.

Comment: This is not working with new version of magento 2 for new version use <css src="css/custom.css" media="all and (min-width: 1px)" />

Comment: You don't need the order, just change the order in the code by moving the code up or down

Comment: @KandarpBPatel This doesn't work for me, it make my custom css run between style-m.css and style-l.css, version magento 2.3.5-p1.